# Can I run an Angular 6 project on WAMP Server?

Tags: php, angular, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I am a PHP developer and also I have developed Angular 6 apps using Node.js backend. But, currently I am working on a project which should run an Angular 6 app with a PHP 7 back-end. The reason is that, the API was written in PHP. I wish to develop my Angular app in WAMP server default directory.

```
wamp64/www/my_project
```

So my questions are,

1. Will the Angular 6 app run? Because it needs another server and normally it is `http://localhost:4200/.`
2. Would there any server (localhost) collisions?
3. If it is, what should I do?
4. Also, can I run `<?php session_start();?>` on the beginning of `index.html(or .php)` file?

Comment: You can run Angular on WAMP. You need to run session_start in a .php file. It needs to process the actual php code.

Comment: @unixmiah Thank you for advice. But could you please tell me or give me any link, how should I implement  session_star on an Angular 6 app? As I know, there is only one index.html available, right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720047/running-php-within-angular

Comment: make sure to use .php file extension

Answer (score 3):

**You can write Angular2 app just using Angular2 packages without using node or mamp or xampp and host that app.**

If you have written any thing in Angular2 and node.js combination then you can host it on free services like Heroku for testing purpose.

**and build app using:**

> ng build --prod

copy dist folder and paste it in my xampp htdocs folder and access the site using:

> localhost:8080/dist/

**output**

App works

Comment: Excellent..!! It means that, I should finish my client side work first. Thank you..! Also, can I then use php session_start function in that index.html file? (of course, I should rename it..)

Comment: I was able to run the app, but not the backend. Do you run the PHP backend on the same server ?

Comment: I am unable to run the app even after following the above mentioned steps. It shows black browser screen and css 404 errors in the log.